# How can I get this React/Redux app to render properly?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've spent the last hour and a half trying to figure out why my React and Redux app is not rendering in my local host. I've tested a couple of other react apps to make sure they are working properly, and they are. However, this is my first time making an app that uses redux, so I don't have a good way of comparing this app to my previous work.

Here is the full code.

```
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {Provider, createStore} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

// Redux:
const ADD = 'ADD';

const addMessage = (message) => {
  return {
    type: ADD,
    message: message
  }
};

const messageReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD:
      return [
        ...state,
        action.message
      ];
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const store = Redux.createStore(messageReducer);

// React:
// const Provider = ReactRedux.Provider;
// const connect = ReactRedux.connect;

// Change code below this line
class Presentational extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      input: '',
      messages: []
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.submitMessage = this.submitMessage.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      input: event.target.value
    });
  }
  submitMessage() {
    this.setState({
      input: '',
      messages: this.state.messages.concat(this.state.input)
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Type in a new Message:</h2>
        <input
          value={this.state.input}
          onChange={this.handleChange}/><br/>
        <button onClick={this.submitMessage}>Submit</button>
        <ul>
          {this.state.messages.map( (message, idx) => {
              return (
                 <li key={idx}>{message}</li>
              )
            })
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
// Change code above this line

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {messages: state}
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    submitNewMessage: (message) => {
      dispatch(addMessage(message))
    }
  }
};

const Container = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Presentational);

class AppWrapper extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Container/>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
};



render(<AppWrapper/>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

Comment: Add the expected behavior. Add how your result differs from the expected one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component [`Provider`](https://react-redux.js.org/api/provider) is from the `react-redux` package. Not `redux`. Import it correctly and it will work.

```js
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { connect, Provider } from 'react-redux';
```

Comment: unfortunately the component still is not rendering in my HTML document. A few things I'm wondering about:

1) I first set up my react-app with "npx create-react-app appname and then used then editied the original files and tried to locally host. It wasn't after the fact the I tried using "npm install redux" and  "npm install redux-react". Could that be causing an issue?

2) in VS Code "import { createStore } from 'redux';" is dimmed in my code editor. Would that point to what my current issue is?

3) The code you presented above, should that be added to my imports or replace them?

Comment: Before I noticed the import error, I had your entire code in a codepen. The only thing I changed was the import and then it rendered for me. I haven't used CRA if a while, but if its running a wepback build you will need to restart it in order for it to find changed to `node_modules`. Typically they get ignored for performance reasons.

Comment: In fact, it looks like I even saved it on accident [here](https://codepen.io/briant1414/pen/ExxVmmX?editors=0011)